# Such SQL query possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, group-by, pivot

Suppose I have table with sales information for different stores that sell fruit, like this:

| Store | Fruit | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | apples | 2 |
| Two | oranges | 5 |
| One | pears | 3 |
| Three | apples | 2 |
| One | oranges | 3 |
| Three | apples | 4 |
| Two | apples | 1 |
| One | pears | 5 |

Is there a way to write SQL query, that would return table with sum of each fruits sold for each store, something like:

| Store | apples | oranges | pears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 2 | 3 | 8 |
| Two | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| Three | 6 | 0 | 0 |

Or must I run 3 different queries, one for each store?
Thanks.

Comment: depends on your dbms. You can do a group, but to get each possible value as its own column is non-standard. Possible on MS-SQL and Oracle

Comment: I have Laravel with MySql. Thank you.

Comment: With MySQL, you can do this directly, if you don't need separate columns.  See: `GROUP_CONCAT`.  You would first aggregate per store/fruit to obtain the sums and then  aggregate per store to apply `GROUP_CONCAT` to pull each fruit/sum per store into the same result row.  There are other approaches, depending on how much you know about the number of fruit or whether you want to take a two step approach, where step 1 builds SQL based on the max number of fruit. Step 2 executes that SQL.

Comment: Please run `SELECT version();` to check specific MySQL version.

Comment: Yes, it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874811/sql-dynamic-column-header-based-on-the-type